# ReportViewer show error when selecting first parameter

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportviewer, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2016

When I select first parameter in report viewer an error is occurred and does not allow me to select date parameters. screen shot is given.

[image]

Another issue is that when I select start date and end date on report viewer and click on View Report button, start date is changed to some other date.

Comment: it's been for 5 hours since post. Is there any person to reply.

Comment: you'll need to add more info. How is your parameter configured, where do the values come from, are there any defaults.
 Also please respect that people who help on here volunteer their time to help others. When people see a question that does not offer a lot of information, they will often ignore it. You can help by following the guidelines here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Values for parameters are coming from table. There is no default value for any of these parameters.